# How do I edit a task in a react/mysql application?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, sql-update, scheduled-tasks

So I am making a ToDo app but so far I can just create a task, or delete it. Right now I am trying to make another feature where I can edit the specific task by clicking the edit button and then it will change the task into an input area where i can edit the task name. Can someone help me with this? How it looks right now is displayed below. [image]

My Code right now is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default class TaskInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            task: " ",
            allTasks: [],
            strikeThrough: {textDecoration:""}
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            task: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    handleStrikethrough = (completed, id) => {
    //    !completed ? this.setState({strikeThrough:{textDecoration: "line-through"}})  : this.setState({strikeThrough:{textDecoration:""}})
            // if (!completed) {
            //     console.log("not completed", !completed)
            //     this.setState({strikeThrough:{textDecoration: "line-through"}});
            //     axios.put("/api/task", {
            //         completed: !completed
            //     }, id).then(response => console.log(response))
            // } else {
            //     this.setState({strikeThrough:{textDecoration:""}})
            //     axios.put("/api/task", {
            //         completed: !completed
            //     }, id).then(response => console.log(response))
            // }
    }

    handleDelete = (taskId) => {
        axios.delete("/api/task/" + taskId).then(data => {
            console.log("You deleted the task with an id of ", data)
        })
        window.location.reload();
    }

    handleTaskEdit = () => {
        console.log("edit button worked")
    }

    submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault() //to prevent page refresh
        console.log()

        fetch("/api/task", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        this.setState({
            task: ""
        })
        window.location.reload()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("component did mount")

        const self = this;
        axios.get("/api/tasks").then(function (data) {
            self.setState({
                allTasks: data.data
            })
            // console.log(self.state.allTasks[0].task)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {strikeThrough, task, allTasks} = this.state; //destructuring the state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} >
                    <label style={{ margin: "5px 0px" }}>Create a Task:</label>
                    <input value={this.state.task} onChange={this.changeHandler} style={{ width: "100%" }}></input>
                    <input style={{ padding: "5px", marginTop: "5px" }} type="submit"></input>
                </form>
                <hr></hr>
                <br></br>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.allTasks.map(task => (
                        <li style={strikeThrough} onClick={()=>this.handleStrikethrough(task.completed, task.id)} className="tasks">{task.task}
                        <button onClick = {() => this.handleDelete(task.id)}>x</button>
                        <button onClick={this.handleTaskEdit}>edit</button>
                        </li>
                    )
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you call window.location.reload?

Answer (score 1):

You could set task ID on its corresponding Edit button, then when clicking Edit button get the task using ID and sending that task to an edit component.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all handleTaskEdit, here you set task name to the task property and set ID of editable task:**

```
handleTaskEdit = id =>
  this.setState({ task: this.state.allTasks.find(el => el.id === id).task })
```

**secondly, create two new methods, createTask and updateTask:**

```
createTask = () => {
        fetch("/api/task", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({task: this.state.task}),

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({
              task: '', 
              allTasks: [...this.state.allTasks, data]}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
updateTask = () => {
    fetch("/api/task", {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({task: this.state.task, id: this.state.editableTaskId}),

    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
          task: '',
          editableTaskId: null,
          allTasks: this.state.allTasks.map(el => 
          el.id === data.id ? data : el)})) // Or take new name and id from state
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

**and finally you need to update submitHandler and handleDelete:**

```
submitHandler = () => {
    if (this.state.editableTaskId) {
      this.updateTask();
    } else {
      this.createTask()
    }
}
handleDelete = (taskId) => {
    axios.delete("/api/task/" + taskId).then(data => {
      this.setState({allTasks: this.state.allTasks.filter(el =>
        el.id !== data.id
      )})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach:

Have a state variable called `editTaskID` and keep the default value as null. On the edit button set the functionality of `handleTaskEdit` in such a way that it sets the `editTaskID` to that particular task ID on which edit button was clicked.

In the map function where you are rendering the list items for tasks, add a condition such as:

```
{this.state.allTasks.map(task =>
             (
               <li style={strikeThrough}
                 onClick={()=>this.handleStrikethrough(task.completed, task.id)} 
                 className="tasks">
                 {
                   this.editTaskID
                   ?<input 
                        value={this.state.editTaskName} 
                        /*supposing editTaskName to be state variable that stores 
                        the edit textfield content.*/ 
                        onChange={this.changeEditHandler} style={{ width: "80%" }}>
                    </input>
                  :task.task
                 }
               <button onClick = {() => this.handleDelete(task.id)}>x</button>
               <button onClick={this.handleTaskEdit}>edit</button>
              </li>
            )
           )
}
```

This will now check the condition whether the editTaskID has been set to null or not while rendering. In case if it is null, all your tasks will come as a plain text else it will come in form of a text box. You can also add the value to the edit task input field with the help of `allTasks[editTaskID]`.

On the `handleTaskEdit` function of the edit button, make sure to set the `allTasks[editTaskID]` to the value `editTaskName` and also to set the state variable `editTaskID` to null.
Call the necessary backend endpoint to reflect the changes in your database as well.

I hope it helps. Thanks.